# Apache reverse proxy subdomain to port

Tags: apache, ubuntu, networking, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to setup an apache reverse-proxy to achive following results.

**Expected Results**

When visiting `https://service.example.com`, apache will serve content from `http://localhost:8080`, which is another service/webserver being run on the localhost.

**Actual Results**

When visiting `https://service.example.com` apache gives back content from `https://example.com` (and gives some certificate issues).

**Current configuartion**

There is an SSL apache server being run at `https://example.com` with a lets encrypt wildcard certificate.

The virtual-host file that is supposed to enable the reverse-proxy looks the following

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName service.example.com

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        ProxyRequests Off
        <Proxy *>
          Order deny,allow
          Allow from all
        </Proxy>

        ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080
        ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080

        <Location />
          Order allow,deny
          Allow from all
        </Location>

   </VirtualHost>
```

The file has been activated with a2ensite service.conf and has symbolic link to `/sites-enabled`

How does one resolve this problem? All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In case the issue is still relevant, you were missing slashes at the end of the domain:

```
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
```

Also, don't forget to enable the proxy modules: a2enmod proxy_http